# different server neo4j database and my codes

Tags: neo4j

i want to use neo4j graph database for my site. my site and my neo4j database are not in the same server. How can I access the neo4j database from another server? Can anyone help me?

When I try to connect like this,

```
GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
```

it works correctly, but when I try to connect like this,

```
GraphClient client = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx:7474/db/data"));
```

it can't connect. What is the problem? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4J is by default configured to accept incoming connections from 127.0.0.1 only.

Edit your `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file, and make sure you have the following set:

```
#allow any client to connect
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

See http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-configuration.html#_important_server_configurations_parameters for more details

Comment: Hello. in localhost no problem, i can work with local ne4oj database. But when I try to connect neo4j database from different server i can not do it.

Comment: Please update your question and provide more information on what you are trying.  It is not easy to guess what you are trying to do - and how.

Comment: stil i can not connect i tried like this, org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0. and i tried like this org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=94.73.147.20.

Comment: not firewall. i stop neo4j and then start again, no problem thank you very much :) i have a new question now is there anyway to let just my ip to use neo4j database?

Comment: install a firewall and make a restriction on the neo4j port to all ips but yours.